# Is there responsive bootstrap popover alternative?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently bootstrap 2.3.2 popover is not responsive. On small screens it opens outside the screen. Is there an alternative?

Thank you

Comment: I think the basic alternative is to design your user interaction so that you do not have any pop-ups, just normal page links for confirmations and such. Though this advice does not serve as drop-in replacement :(

Comment: Thx Mikko, I agree with you but is out of my control.

Comment: Is it a good idea for showing bootstrap popover for small screens at all? Actually - what is "small" screen?

Answer (score 6):

I use this method in the meanwhile for better popover placement, should work with Bootstrap 2 and 3:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
    // Add more else stuff with parentheses for more sizes
    placement: function() { return $(window).width() < 975 ? 'top' : 'right'; }
});
```

If you have issues the popover width, first ensure the `container` parameter has a proper value, e.g. `container: 'body'`.

Answer (score 3):

For responsive behavior, Bootstrap 3 has **auto** value for **placement**.

E.g.

placement: 'auto left'

[Bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto left", the tooltip will display to the left when possible, otherwise it will display right.

Comment: Auto for placement is buggy yet, and won't be fixed until Bootstrap 4: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15367

Answer (score 0):

There are more improvement in recent development. you should try latest version of bootstrap Currently v3.1.1 .

Comment: 3 seems to have the same problem

Comment: just open boostrap 3 popovers on your phone and click the sample button. You can see that the popover is off screen. Maybe the way to fix this is that on small screens switch to a popover top or bottom solution or a modal solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me ..

```
if ($(window).width() < 800){
    $('.prioritypopups').data('placement','right');
} else {
    $('.prioritypopups').data('placement','left');
}

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

However this is technically not responsive but does respond to different page sizes.